# will variables defined in non static method be garbage collected with object

Tags: garbage-collection, non-static

```
class Utility{
    public String a = "aaaa huge string";

    public void doSomething() {
        String b = "bbbb huge string";
        .....
    }
}
```

given class Utility, here are my method calls.

```
Step 1)  Utility u = new Utility();
Step 2)  u.doSomething();
Step 3)  u = null;
```

When object u is garbage collected after step 3, will the String b also be removed from the String pool?

When will strings a and b be loaded and removed (if at all) from memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined in methods are not members of the instance, so the GC of objects they reference is completely independent of the GC of the instance.

> When object u is garbage collected after step 3

*If* object `u` is garbage collected after step 3

> will the String b also be removed from the String pool?

`u` has nothing to do with `b`: see above.

> When will strings a and b be loaded and removed (if at all) from memory?

Loaded with the class, because they are string literals. Removal depends on GC and interning.

Comment: I want few string constants to be defined in code, and since these strings are huge, I dont want them to sit in memory after they are used. Is there a way to define them in code. This is relevant for android where memory is an expensive resource.